# How to make keyboard disappear on Iphone form with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-validate

I have a form that is composed of 3 pages. On a iphone I'm trying to get the keyboard to disappear and would also like the page to zoom page to original size when the GO button is pushed.

I tried the following JS function:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function(event) {
    // If enter is pressed then hide keyboard.
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("input").blur();
    }
});
```

but that brings me back to the first page.  Here's a link to a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4xktv9k/3/)
With the JS function above it works on the first page but on the second page with the function or not when I press GO it goes back to the first page.

That seems like strange behavior. Without the function at all, the GO button, when pressed on the first page brings me to the second page (desired behavior) but when on the second page and the GO button is pressed it looks like it's submitting the form - desired behavior is to either close the keyboard or go to page 3

I'm getting a CSRF verification failed when trying this on the iphone from JS fiddle when on page 2.  Any ideas?

When I add debug:true to the validate jquery it works.  My understanding is debug:true prevents form submission.  How do I do this properly?

Comment: The last part about jQuery Validate has nothing to do with the rest of the question.   Yes, `debug: true` will put jQuery Validate into debug mode and prevent submission... so how to do what properly?

Comment: The `.validate()` method should not be inside of a click handler.  This method is only used to initialize the plugin on your form and would get called once on DOM ready.

Comment: *"I'm getting a CSRF verification failed"* ~ Sounds more like an error that would be coming from your server-side code, because it's not coming from the JavaScript you've shown us.

Comment: sparky, there is no server side code.  also, the validate method is inside a click handler because I have a single form that is being displayed over 3 pages. and lastly although probably should be first it seems like the problem is pressing GO button submits form. how do I prevent this?

Comment: So then what's doing the CSRF verification?

Comment: If i access the js fiddle from an iphone it happens there

Comment: There is no good reason to have the `.validate()` method inside a `click` handler at all.  It's only **initializing** the plugin, so hitting it on every click is pointless.

Comment: <form><fieldset></fieldset><fieldset></fieldset><fieldset></fieldset></form>  each fieldset is displayed on a page.  When the first one is displayed the other two are hidden.   Once the entire form is fil;led out it's submitted once.

Comment: Again, you seem to misunderstand the purpose of the `.validate()` method.  It's not called to trigger validation... it's only called once to initialize the validation plugin.

Comment: @sparky, thanks.  I moved the .validate to under the document.ready().  The UI is actually more responsive! I guess that makes sense but surprised at how noticeable it was.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

seems to do the trick